# Displaying translucent / irregular-shaped windows with Qt

Tags: windows, user-interface, qt, cross-platform, transparency

Is it possible to display translucent and/or irregular-shaped windows with Qt?

(I'm assuming it ultimately depends on the capabilities of the underlying GUI system, but let's assume at least Windows XP / Mac OS X)

If so, how does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The key is the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute of `QWidget`

Here is a simple class that draws a round translucent window with a red background 50% alpha.

### TranslucentRoundWindow.h:

```
#include <QWidget>

class TranslucentRoundWindow : public QWidget
{
    public:
        TranslucentRoundWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        virtual QSize sizeHint() const;

    protected:
        virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paintEvent);
};
```

### TranslucentRoundWindow.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "TranslucentRoundWindow.h"

TranslucentRoundWindow::TranslucentRoundWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent, Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
}

QSize TranslucentRoundWindow::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(300, 300);
}

void TranslucentRoundWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 127));

    painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, width(), height());
}
```

If you want to be able to move this window with the mouse, you will have to override `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`.

Comment: Copied & pasted above and all I get is a black square with a red circle inside. What am I missing?

Comment: On what OS have you tried? This works fine on Windows and OS X. Also, what Qt version are you using? This answer was written with Qt 4.4 or 4.5 if I remember correctly.

Comment: Linux 3.1.0 64bit, Qt 4.6.3. The examples that comes with QT all work fine.

Comment: On Windows you have to had `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);` in the window constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly is possible. Qt ships with the "Shaped Clock" demonstration. The documentation of which is [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/widgets-shapedclock.html).

It creates a top-level window with an odd shape. Should be all you need.

Comment: This does not address the translucent part of the question.