# QWidget per-pixel translusency

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking at making a QWidget partially transluscent.

[QWidget::setMask](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#setMask) can set a per-pixel transparency, [like this](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/widgets-shapedclock.html), but it's either-or: not transluscent.

[QWidget::opacity](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) can set a global transluscency, but it's not per-pixel.

How can I get the best of both worlds and add a per-pixel alpha channel to the whole widget? (Decorations don't matter.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333610/displaying-translucent-irregular-shaped-windows-with-qt and for the per-Pixel part you can paint a `QPixmap` with an alpha channel as the background.

Comment: Have to agree with the above comment. Follow the setup in the link above and paint what you want in the paint event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [QWidget::setMaks()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#setMask)?

```
QLabel topLevelLabel;
QPixmap pixmap(":/images/tux.png");
topLevelLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
topLevelLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask());
```

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, that's not transluscent (the mask it a bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the QStyle class is what you might be looking for, esp. QStyle::drawItemPixmap; then use QWidget::setStyle().  Never used this myself though.