# How to make different message windows in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, plugins

I am beginner of Python, does anyone knows how to make a different shapes of message windows in python? i want to design a better look and friendly GUI.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **Qt** is what may be useful to you. Take a look at the documentation on [QtProject homepage](http://qt-project.org/). Lots of tutorials can be found on the Internet. For your specific problem take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347163/pyqt-irregularly-shaped-windows-e-g-a-circular-without-a-border-decorations).