# How to draw a custom shaped window using Qt and apply current Windows theme colors/effects to it?

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface, themes, aero-glass

Is it possible to draw a custom shaped window in Qt which inherits color and transparency (glass) effects from current system theme. Ultimately I need it to look & feel just like user's taskbar adjusting to his theme. Like in this [concept](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/22/16gnyo.png). I realize that it might not be possible to achieve such perfect integration, but at least make a custom shaped background which look the same as the taskbar (glass look&feel) I believe is achievable.

Partially it is answered in similar questoin - [Displaying translucent / irregular-shaped windows with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333610/displaying-translucent-irregular-shaped-windows-with-qt). But still not sure how to read system theme information and apply it to QPainter.

Comment: [Qt Windows 7 extend frame into client area with transparency](http://nicug.blogspot.fr/2011/03/qt-windows-7-extend-frame-into-client.html). Thanks to this post, I've managed to apply system blur to my frame, but it still [quite differs](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6587/protoed.png) from the taskbar blur. Is it possible to adjust the color/blurrness this way? Plus I couldn't find a way to apply this approach to irregular window shape from the example mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that slope on the left. I'd wager you could get a title bar on a window to be taller and have the rest of the window be 0 height so the window was entirely a title bar but that slope would require rendering functions that just won't exist on Windows.

Also, you're wanting your window hide the taskbar's bevel under where your window appears. That will probably not be possible either as your window will be semi-transparent so it won't be able to block the rendered bevel of the normal taskbar.

Sorry. Might have to go back to the drawing board on your design.

Comment: I agree, the slope part might be too much, so I decided to stick to standard rectangular shape. And as you mentioned, the bevel effect makes it tricky to integrate it seemingly.
So far I've managed to apply system blur, but still it has not the same look as the taskbar:
http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/6587/protoed.png