# Arrow popup dialog in Qt

Tags: qt

In Qt does anyone know how to do a popup tool-dialog with an arrow like this?

[Popup from KScreen http://www.airwebreathe.org.uk/space/popup-dialog.jpg](http://www.airwebreathe.org.uk/space/popup-dialog.jpg)

I found this in a blog about KDEs new KScreen GUI. I presume this was achieved with Qt5. Does anyone know if this is possible with Qt4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a Plasma [Dialog](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma/QML/API#Dialog) QML widget ([see the relevant code here](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kscreen.git&a=blob&h=f8245cf75d6ca05c67d3c7bb6945a9bdc2783fd3&hb=b77b01bc406e472bbca991a24cb8929b789c8f9f&f=kcm/qml/OutputControls.qml#l274)). You can create translucent, irregularly shaped windows in Qt 4 quite easily, though. There’s already an answer for that:

[**Displaying translucent / irregular-shaped windows with Qt**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333610/displaying-translucent-irregular-shaped-windows-with-qt)